# Writing to multiple elasticsearch clusters from logstash

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I have two ES clusters with cluster 1 running on 2.4.x version and cluster 2 running on 5.1.1 version. Currently logstash (5.x version) is writing indexes to cluster 1 (2.4.x) with the following output configuration in logstash:

```
    output {
  elasticsearch {
        hosts => "cluster1:9200"
                index => "index-pattern-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                sniffing => "true"
                template_overwrite => true
    }}
```

I want to feed live data to cluster2 (5.1.1 version) by changing the following logstash output configuration file to:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
        hosts => "cluster1:9200"
                index => "index-pattern-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                sniffing => "true"
                template_overwrite => true
    }
  elasticsearch {
        hosts => "cluster2:9200"
                index => "index-pattern-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                sniffing => "true"
                template_overwrite => true
    }
}
```

Is this possible? Or is there any better idea for feeding live data to two different clusters?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have two such outputs, but note that, if one blocks, the other will, too.

Comment: Is there a way i can avoid blocking? or is there any other way of doing this?